# What is the memory overhead of a .NET Object

Tags: c#, .net

What is the memory overhead of an Object in .NET?  I'm talking about an arbitrary bare-bones object.... the overhead of the internal .NET workings or references:

```
var obj = new System.Object();
```

How much space does obj occupy in the heap?

Comment: Heap and stack are implementation details.

Comment: @ThePower: Not a duplicate.  That other question (and its answers) don't talk about the basic memory overhead of a .NET object at all.

Comment: @ThePower It doesn't answer my question, I want to know the memory overhead, not how to measure it

Comment: @asawyer - could you explain your comment?  I thought a heap was an abstract data structure in which all objects are stored... why is it wrong to ask "How much space does it occupy in the heap"?

Comment: How does: "You could use a memory profiler like .NET Memory Profiler...." answer my question????

Comment: @reach4thelasers: Why can't you just measure it to find out?

Comment: @reach4thelasers http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I talk about this in a blog post ["Of memory and strings"](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings/). It's implementation-specific, but for the Microsoft .NET CLR v4, the x86 CLR has a per-object overhead of 8 bytes, and the x64 CLR has a per-object overhead of 16 bytes.

However, there are *minimum* sizes of 12 and 24 bytes respectively - it's just that you get the first 4 or 8 bytes "free" when you start storing useful information :)

(See the blog post for more information.)

Comment: There may be padding for member variables to fit on address boundaries as well. This padding concept further complicates the calculation of memory overhead of an object. No wonder C# never introduced sizeof operator for instance variables for types.

Comment: I ran a few tests in a .net console app to check memory usage. Creating 10 million empty objects resulted in ca 340MB usage (includes the list with references). Adding 1 or 2 integers to the class changed nothing. Only when adding the 3rd integer did I see an increase to ca 430MB. This fully supports your statement of 24 bytes minimum with 8 bytes free for information.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet could you add a generic definition for "memory overhead"? I dont really understand what it is. It's like an extra memory allocated for each object? Thank you

Comment: @BorisD: Yes - it's the memory required in addition to the "obvious" memory required for the data itself. (Housekeeping information etc.)