# How custom typs consume memory for props in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

Does initializing custom type do initialization for all props inside it ?
I am asking this regarding performance  and consumption of memory at client.
In dot net if I create custom type something like

```
   public class myCustomType 
   {
     public string prop1 {get;set;}
     public string prop2 {get;set;}
     public string prop3 {get;set;}
     public string prop4 {get;set;}
    }
```

when somewhere else in code I do

```
var parOfmyCustomType = new myCustomType (){ prop1 = "stingToHold" };
var listOfCustom = new list<myCustomType>(){ parOfmyCustomType };
```

Regrading of memory consumed, does my app using memory for all sting props when I create myCustomType and set prop vale of only one

Comment: What do you get from myCustomType mt = new myCustomType();  Debug.WriteLine(mt.prop1); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create properties with an empty get; set; definition the class the property is basically equal to the following:

```
public class myCustomType {
  private string _prop1;
  private string _prop2;
  private string _prop3;
  private string _prop4;

  public string prop1 {
    get { return _prop1; }
    set { _prop1 = value; }
  }
  public string prop1 {
    get { return _prop1; }
    set { _prop1 = value; }
  }
  public string prop3 {
    get { return _prop; }
    set { _prop1 = value; }
  }
  public string prop4 {
    get { return _prop4; }
    set { _prop4 = value; }
  }
}
```

The backing string fields (_prop1 - _prop4)are initialized to null (as are all reference types in C#). So bascially the data portion of that class would contain 4 "pointers" to strings that initially all point to null (depending on architecture that would be 4 * 32 bits or 4 * 64 bits or 16/32 bytes for every instance of the custom type.

Each string you create will use it's own memory (well, not always - you might want to search for "string interning"). But no memory gets allocated inside the custom type to store string data if that is what you're concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of `myCustomType` will contain four string references plus [the usual per instance overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655829/what-is-the-memory-overhead-of-a-net-object). If an instance points to four strings these take up memory as well.