# Memory usage of dynamic type in c#

Tags: c#, sizeof, dynamictype

Whether does dynamic-type use more memory size, than relevant type?

For example, does the field use only four bytes?

```
dynamic foo = (int) 1488;
```

Comment: The underlying variable is still an `int`, so yes the value is 4 bytes. There will be some additional general overhead for the program to use dynamic, though.

Comment: At its root, `dynamic` is just an `object` that uses a bunch of fancy Reflection to make it act like a dynamic type. It's not going to take up any more or less data than the type it actually represents.

Comment: Your answer is here. (Pay attention to the first example. The dynamic type and object type both return System.Int32 type.) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx

Comment: @Abion47 if that _uses a bunch of fancy Reflection to make it act like a dynamic type_ then how does it use only 4 bytes? are you sure it has no overhead or any garbage creation? do you have reference?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary The same way you can use reflection on a normal `Int32`, because that's all `dynamic` really does..

Comment: There's *definitely* overhead. It takes a lot of behind-the-scenes stuff to make `dynamic` work. But the *value* it produces is still going to be a standard `int`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer**:

No. It will actually use 12 bytes on 32bit machine and 24 bytes on 64 bit.

**Long Answer**

A `dynamic` type will be stored as an object but at run time the compiler will load many more bytes to make sense of what to do with the `dynamic` type. In order to do that, a lot more memory will be used to figure that out. Think of `dynamic` as a *fancy* object.

Here is a class:

```
class Mine
{
}
```

Here is the overhead for the above object on 32bit:

```
--------------------------  -4 bytes 
|  Object Header Word    |
|------------------------|  +0 bytes
|  Method Table Pointer  |
|------------------------|  +4 bytes for Method Table Pointer
```

A total of 12 bytes needs to be allocated to it since the smallest reference type on 32bit is 12 bytes.

If we add one field to that class like this:

```
class Mine
{
    public int Field = 1488;
}
```

It will still take 12 bytes because the overhead and the `int` field can fit in the 12 bytes.

If we add another `int` field, it will take 16 bytes.

However, if we add one `dynamic` field to that class like this:

```
class Mine
{
    public dynamic Field = (int)1488;
}
```

It will **NOT** be 12 bytes. The dynamic field will be treated like an `object` and thus the size will be 12 + 12 = 24 bytes.

What is interesting is if you do this instead:

```
class Mine
{
    public dynamic Field = (bool)false;
}
```

An instance of `Mine` will still take 24 bytes because even though the dynamic fields is only a boolean, it is still treated like an `object`.

On a 64bit machine, an instance of `Mine` with dynamic will take 48 bytes since the smallest reference type on 64 bit is 24 bytes (24 + 24 = 48 bytes).

[Here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter14/DynamicGotchas.aspx) are some *gotchas* you should be aware of and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655829/what-is-the-memory-overhead-of-a-net-object) answer for size of `object`.